# Install sonarlint plugin in eclipse offline

Tags: eclipse-plugin, sonarlint-eclipse

I have some systems, due to security issues we have kept them without internet. How do we install sonarlint plugin in eclipse offline on them? What are manual steps to install? From where we download this jar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For offline installation and older versions see the update site archive at
https://bintray.com/sonarsource/SonarLint-for-Eclipse/releases

Comment: Provided link is showing only the  .zip   folder of plugin . what i need to do of this folder now.

Comment: This link is related to the question?

Comment: This link is dead (bintray has been discontinued), but the site zip files can be found here: https://binaries.sonarsource.com/SonarLint-for-Eclipse/releases

Answer (score 10):

From another post...

1. Download your plugin
2. Open Eclipse
3. From the menu choose: `Help` / `Install New Software...`
4. Click the `Add` button
5. In the `Add Repository` dialog that appears, click the `Archive` button next to the `Location` field
6. Select your plugin file, click `OK`

You could also just copy plugins to the `eclipse/plugins` directory, but it's [not recommended](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_install_new_plug-ins%3F).

Answer (score 1):

Please install version 5.3 from the below link
https://community.sonarsource.com/t/how-to-download-plugins-for-off-line-use/29281
Go to Eclipse -> Help -> Install new software.
Add the v5.3 archive which you downloaded and click on next