# SonarLint on eclipse : Unable to start standalone SonarLint engine

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarlint

After installing the sonarLint plugin in offline mode on eclipse, and after restarting eclipse, this error was displayed :

```
Unable to start standalone SonarLint engine
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component interface org.sonar.api.batch.rule.Rules
```

The full log is :

```
Unable to start standalone SonarLint engine
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component interface org.sonar.api.batch.rule.Rules
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:59)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:678)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.ComponentContainer.getComponentByType(ComponentContainer.java:258)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.standalone.rule.StandaloneRuleRepositoryContainer.doAfterStart(StandaloneRuleRepositoryContainer.java:64)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:125)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:110)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.standalone.StandaloneGlobalContainer.loadRulesAndActiveRulesFromPlugins(StandaloneGlobalContainer.java:126)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.standalone.StandaloneGlobalContainer.doAfterStart(StandaloneGlobalContainer.java:99)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:125)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.StandaloneSonarLintEngineImpl.start(StandaloneSonarLintEngineImpl.java:64)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.StandaloneSonarLintEngineImpl.<init>(StandaloneSonarLintEngineImpl.java:52)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.StandaloneSonarLintClientFacade.getClient(StandaloneSonarLintClientFacade.java:60)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.StandaloneSonarLintClientFacade.runAnalysis(StandaloneSonarLintClientFacade.java:74)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.AnalyzeProjectJob.run(AnalyzeProjectJob.java:456)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.AnalyzeProjectJob.runAnalysisAndUpdateMarkers(AnalyzeProjectJob.java:204)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.AnalyzeProjectJob.doRun(AnalyzeProjectJob.java:160)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.AbstractSonarProjectJob.runInWorkspace(AbstractSonarProjectJob.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.standalone.rule.StandaloneRuleDefinitionsLoader
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:59)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getMemberArguments(SingleMemberInjector.java:61)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.getMemberArguments(MethodInjector.java:100)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector$2.run(MethodInjector.java:112)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.decorateComponentInstance(MethodInjector.java:120)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.CompositeInjector.decorateComponentInstance(CompositeInjector.java:58)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.Reinjector.reinject(Reinjector.java:142)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ProviderAdapter.getComponentInstance(ProviderAdapter.java:96)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:57)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.script.ScriptEngine.eval(String)" because the return value of "javax.script.ScriptEngineManager.getEngineByName(String)" is null
    at org.sonarsource.analyzer.commons.JsonParser.<init>(JsonParser.java:36)
    at org.sonarsource.analyzer.commons.ProfileDefinitionReader.loadActiveKeysFromJsonProfile(ProfileDefinitionReader.java:59)
    at org.sonarsource.analyzer.commons.RuleMetadataLoader.<init>(RuleMetadataLoader.java:60)
    at org.sonar.plugins.php.PHPRulesDefinition.define(PHPRulesDefinition.java:37)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.standalone.rule.StandaloneRuleDefinitionsLoader.<init>(StandaloneRuleDefinitionsLoader.java:39)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector.newInstance(AbstractInjector.java:145)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:342)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:57)
    ... 33 more

Found 0 issue(s)
```

Comment: That's not the full log. The full log starts with `!SESSION` and is stored in the workspace in `.metadata/.log`.

Comment: thank you for your comment but I'm talking about the console log. for the eclipse log there is no information related to sonarLint

Comment: I see. The root problem seems to be that the JavaScript engine is required, which was included in older versions of Java, but is no longer included in more recent versions. Is your SonarLint  up to date?

Comment: Sincerely I don't have a big idea, I used the answer given in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51494982/install-sonarlint-plugin-in-eclipse-offline)

Comment: That seems to be outdated. Grab https://binaries.sonarsource.com/SonarLint-for-Eclipse/releases/5.9.0.31414/ with the subfolders `features` and `plugins` instead.

Comment: I tried with the latest version and it worked fine, thanks a lot for your help, you can add it as an answer if you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the log, the **JavaScript engine is missing**, which was included in older Java versions, but [has been **removed in Java 15**](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/372).

**Make sure, your SonarLint is up to date**. For offline installation you can grab the latest release from https://binaries.sonarsource.com/SonarLint-for-Eclipse/releases, which is currently, [5.9.0.31414](https://binaries.sonarsource.com/SonarLint-for-Eclipse/releases/org.sonarlint.eclipse.site-5.9.0.31414.zip).